# fancybox's bug: a colorful cross-page environment make the frame colored

Tags: fancybox

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={75mm,100mm},
margin=20pt]{geometry}


\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\fancypage{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{12pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.4pt}%
\setlength{\shadowsize}{0pt}%
\shadowbox}{}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{enumerate}
[leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=\parindent]\item[]\color{red}}{\end{enumerate}}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{quote}
abc\\abc\\abc\\abc\\abc
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

How could I eliminate the effect?

Comment: Er... why are you abusing `enumerate` that way when you don't actually want any numbers? What exactly is the redefinition of `quote` intended to achieve?

Comment: Can you not specify the colour for the box? Right now, it will use whatever the current colour is. So, if it is red when the page breaks, it will use red. The same thing will happen if you say `\textcolor{red}{some text}` and there's a page break between `some` and `text`.

Answer (score 2):

Since in this case the `\fancypage` command isn't very *fancy*,  this is an alternative solution with `tikz` and `eso-pic`.

Replace

```
\usepackage{fancybox}
\fancypage{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{12pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.4pt}%
\setlength{\shadowsize}{0pt}%
\shadowbox}{}
```

with

```
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=0.4pt,black]
      ($ (current page.north east) + (0mm,-5mm) $)--
      ($ (current page.north west) + (4mm,-5mm) $)--
      ($ (current page.south west) + (4mm,0mm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={75mm,100mm},
margin=20pt]{geometry}


\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor,lipsum}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=0.4pt,black]
      ($ (current page.north east) + (0mm,-5mm) $)--
      ($ (current page.north west) + (4mm,-5mm) $)--
      ($ (current page.south west) + (4mm,0mm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{enumerate}
[leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=\parindent]\item[]\color{red}}{\end{enumerate}}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{quote}
abc\\abc\\abc\\abc\\abc
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]